# Integrating a screen pen to Jitsi-meet electron desktop app

Tags: electron, jitsi-meet

I would like to add some features to Jitsi-meet electron desktop app for online education purposes. The thing I'm searching for is, is it possible to add a pen which enable user to draw screen even if the app is in screenshare mode or minimized? Thanks in advance.